# Can't upgrade from 16.04 to 18.04

Tags: 16.04, 18.04, upgrade

When i go to the software updater it says the software is up to date and it says i can upgrade,when i click on it it closes and nothing happens for a while,a restart re-do it again but still doesn't work.

Just found out on console that 5 packages can be upgraded:

```
cuda/unknown 10.1.105-1 amd64 [upgradable from: 9.1.85-1]
cuda-drivers/unknown 418.40.04-1 amd64 [upgradable from: 387.26-1]
libunity-control-center1/xenial-updates 15.04.0+16.04.20171130-0ubuntu1 amd64 [upgradable from: 15.04.0+16.04.20160705-0ubuntu1]
unity-control-center/xenial-updates 15.04.0+16.04.20171130-0ubuntu1 amd64 [upgradable from: 15.04.0+16.04.20160705-0ubuntu1] 
unity-control-center-faces/xenial-updates,xenial-updates 15.04.0+16.04.20171130-0ubuntu1 all [upgradable from: 15.04.0+16.04.20160705-0ubuntu1]
```

Comment: Please check console output of `sudo apt update` or `sudo do-release-upgrade` and add their error output to question (if any). Also please note that 16.04 LTS is supported until 2021 and you may not need to upgrade it.

Comment: I've figured out the problem,when i did it with the console software upgrader it told me i have to update the software first then upgrade it,wich i already did.

Comment: Just found out on console that 5 packages can be upgraded,how do i do that?

Comment: cuda/unknown 10.1.105-1 amd64 [upgradable from: 9.1.85-1]
cuda-drivers/unknown 418.40.04-1 amd64 [upgradable from: 387.26-1]
libunity-control-center1/xenial-updates 15.04.0+16.04.20171130-0ubuntu1 amd64 [upgradable from: 15.04.0+16.04.20160705-0ubuntu1]
unity-control-center/xenial-updates 15.04.0+16.04.20171130-0ubuntu1 amd64 [upgradable from: 15.04.0+16.04.20160705-0ubuntu1]
unity-control-center-faces/xenial-updates,xenial-updates 15.04.0+16.04.20171130-0ubuntu1 all [upgradable from: 15.04.0+16.04.20160705-0ubuntu1]

Comment: `sudo apt-get upgrade`

Comment: @Emmet i see codes popping out,then nothing happens.

Comment: @KirilRistovski Nothing happens? Please post the full output